# Bootstrap+Angular -> Positioning the label in the right place

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am having trouble with moving a text to the right.

```
<mat-form-field class="form-control">
  <mat-label>Move this text:</mat-label>
  <input type="text" required
         placeholder=""
         aria-label="Move this text:"
         matInput
         (input) = "onValueChanged()"
         [formControl]="myControl"
         [(ngModel)]="thisVal"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelect($event)" [displayWith]="displayValueName.bind(this)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options| async" [value]="valueOption" >
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

How it looks like:

1. When clicked somewhere else:
   [image: Label to move]
2. When clicked in autocomplete
   [image: Label to stay]

Best what I have done so far is:

```
.mat-form-field-label.ng-star-inserted.mat-empty.mat-form-field-empty{
                margin-left: 7px;
        }
```

And result is:
3. [image: Wrong 1]
So here: text "jumps" to the left.
4. [image: Wrong 2]
5. [image: Wrong 3]

My problem is to set "Move this text" label like on screen 3 and 5. Without 4th screen behaviour.
Only when: area-expanded=false and is not focused on input.

Do you have any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Siblings...

```css
input.mat-input-element[aria-expanded="false"]~span label.mat-form-field-empty {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```